# When using RDP to connect to a Windows 8 computer how can I send Win hot key combinations?

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

When using remote desktop to connect to a Windows 8 computer <kbd>Win Key</kbd> combinations are not being sent to the remote computer. Is there a way to pass them to the remote computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're connecting from a Windows 7 go to the options dialog:

[image: Options button]

And there under `Local Resources` change the keyboard configuration:

[image: Local Resources]

That should send the combinations to the other computer.